# how to map float to 32 bit integer in python

Tags: python, floating-point

From the AR Drone Developer's guide:

> The number −0.8 is stored in memory as a 32-
>   bit word whose value is BF 4CCCCD (16) , according to the IEEE-754 format.  This 32-bit word
>   can be considered as holding the 32-bit integer value −1085485875 (10).

Is there an "easy way" (built-in functions/existing modules) to do this in python ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe not the best method, but it works.

```
import struct
s = struct.pack("f", -0.8)
i = struct.unpack("i", s)
print i
```

Comment: I disagree as to "maybe not the best method" - it is "the one obvious way" to do it. Actually, there is another weay I'd consider "pythonic" of doing it using ctypes, but unlike the jack in @eryksun's comment, I'd use a ctype Union type.